Parameterized QuarkusTest with TestSecurity
I was wondering if there is a way to parameterize the QuarkustTests and TestSecurity can be parameterized? Currently I have something like this
@QuarkusTest
class MyTest {

    @Inject
    Testservice testee;

    @Test
    @TestSecurity(user = "a", roles = "a")
    void testWithRole_a_throwsException() {
        assertThrows(ForbiddenException.class, () -> testee.myMethod());
    }

    @Test
    @TestSecurity(user = "b", roles = "b")
    void testWithRole_b_throwsException() {
        assertThrows(ForbiddenException.class, () -> testee.myMethod());
    }

}

I would be better if I could do something like this:
@QuarkusTest
class MyTest {


    @Inject
    Testservice testee;

    static Stream<TestUser> testUserDataProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
                new TestUser("a", "a"),
                new TestUser("b", "b")
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testUserDataProvider")
    void testWithRole_throwsException(TestUser testUser) {
        TestSecurity annotation = new TestSecurity(testUser.username, testUser.role);
        assertThrows(ForbiddenException.class, () -> testee.myMethod());
    }

    private record TestUser(String username, String role) {}

}

Unfortunately, I have not found anything like this or anything similar anywhere.
Many thanks and regards

We don't have anything like that

No that's not possible, but you could do this:
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(emptyValue = " ", textBlock = """
            admin, admin, 200
            wrongUser, wrongPassword, 401
            correctUserWithWrongRole, 12345, 403
            ,,401
          """)
void checkUser(String username, String password, int expectedStatus) {
   given()
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
        .auth().basic(username, password)
   .when()
       .get("/api/fruits")
   .then()
       .statusCode(expectedStatus);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(textBlock = """
            GET, /api/fruits, 200
            DELETE, /api/fruits, 403
            GET, /api/forbidden-fruits, 403
           //etc.
          """)
@TestSecurity(user = "correctUser", roles = {"notAdmin", "user"})
void checkAuthorization(String method, String path, int expectedStatus) {
    given()
         .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
    when()
         .request(method, path)
    then()
         .statusCode(expectedStatus);
}

