How pass authorization in Quarkus test
I have this test
    @Test
public void testInvalidLimitExceptionMapping() {
    String errorMessage = "Invalid offset or limit values.";
    String json = mapErrorToJson(errorMessage);

    Mockito.when(orderService.getOrders(anyInt(), anyInt(), anyString()))
            .thenThrow(new InvalidParameterException(errorMessage));

    given()
            .when().get("/v1/orders?offset=5&limit=10&date=2023-04-03")
            .then()
            .statusCode(400)
            .body(is(json));
}

after making endpoint authenticated now it doesn't pass how can I handle auth part?

See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78270267/parameterized-quarkustest-with-testsecurity

I used that @Testsecurity but doesn't work

The RestAssured javadoc has examples on how it can be done, make sure to check it out: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/RestAssured.html
For example you can add something like this:
.auth().preemptive().basic("testUser", "testPassword") to your test REST call setup.
